# MongoDB .NET exception: Unsupported filter

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

I am currently using .NET wrapper for mongodb (refer following excerpt from packages.config for versions):

```
 <package id="mongocsharpdriver" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Bson" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Driver" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Driver.Core" version="2.4.2" targetFramework="net461" />
```

I am trying to build a simple filter to obtain items of which location's Latitude and Longitude is within certain limits as defined by LatitudeDelta and LongitudeDelta.

```
bool filterAll = string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || username == "*";

var filter = Builders<Models.MapQuery>.Filter.Where(p => (filterAll || (username == p.CreatorUsername))
                && Math.Abs(p.PinLocation.Latitude - desiredLatitude) < latitudeDelta
                && Math.Abs(p.PinLocation.Longitude - desiredLongitude) < longitudeDelta);

var queries = await db.GetCollection<Models.MapQuery>(Constants.MAP_QUERY)
                    .Find(filter)
                    .ToListAsync();
```

When the program executes "var queries" line, it hit an exception saying "**Abs(({PinLocation.Latitude} - 3.209096)) is not supported.**".

How do I fix the above exception? Otherwise, what would be the workaround if the above problem cannot be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Maby this works?

```
var filter = Builders<Models.MapQuery>.Filter.And(
        Builders<Models.MapQuery>.Filter.Eq(p => p.username, username),
        Builders<Models.MapQuery>.Filter.Lt(p => Math.Abs(p.PinLocation.Latitude - desiredLatitude), latitudeDelta),
        Builders<Models.MapQuery>.Filter.Lt(p => Math.Abs(p.PinLocation.Longitude - desiredLongitude), longitudeDelta));
```

I changed code to use built in API calls for more readability. I would suggest you do first check before even executing query.